# Back button doesn't work

Tags: java, android, navigation

I have an application with two activities. In the first activity it is possible to start the second by clicking a button.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity, SecondAcitivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Bizarrely, clicking the back button in the second activity doesn't bring me back. I thought such basic behavior is already implemented so that I don't have to do anything about it. Actually in other apps I wrote there never has arisen such a problem.

Of course in the class of the first activity I have

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    firstActivity = this;
    ...
}
```

Comment: check your manifest for activity's launch mode

Comment: have ayou overridden the onkeypressed or onbackpressed method? also check your launcher mode of an activity.

Comment: Can you please provide source for SecondActivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done something to intercept the key event?

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//not invoke the super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I wrote a special behavior for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN` in the `onKeyDown` method. For all other `KeyEvents` I return `false`. So apparently `return false;` doesn't help here. Now I added your `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` instead of returning `false` and everything works fine. Thanks a lot!